# Spring Boot - Embedded Tomcat - Shutdown Hook Hangs

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When running embedded Tomcat, my app sometimes fails to shut down via the /shutdown endpoint.  A thread dump reveals that every thread is either BLOCKED, or IN_NATIVE.  Below is a thread dump.

https://gist.github.com/aglassman/9d6a5e1d121af871345a72e25db6319f

Does this look typical?  Should I continue investigating if there are blocked threads causing shutdown to fail, or should I look elsewhere?

Comment: Most threads are in BLOCKED status are either waits or sleep or park...meaning they are idle. Are you sure your /shutdown endpoint has been hit?

Comment: how have xou configured your shutdown hook. put the code as well

Comment: I've configured it using:

endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.sensitive=false
endpoints.beans.sensitive=false

It works sometimes.  After more investigation, I think it may be an issue with the deploy script doing things out of order.  Thanks for the input MinhKieu and pvpkiran.